# how can i get value of object start with @

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have an object , i get from amazon response. It is like this object convert from xml with `simplexml_load_string` :

```
["@attributes"]=> array(2) {
    ["condition"]=> string(3) "new" 
    ["fulfillmentChannel"]=> string(6) "Amazon"
}
```

i want to get the value of attributes. 
how can i get that??!!
thanks!

---

when i convert xml , attributes shown like [@attributes] .. this is a part of xml :

```
        <BuyBoxEligibleOffers>
            <OfferCount condition="new" fulfillmentChannel="Amazon">1</OfferCount>
            <OfferCount condition="new" fulfillmentChannel="Merchant">10</OfferCount>
        </BuyBoxEligibleOffers>
```

Comment: What steps have you taken to resolve this so far? Please post that as well

Comment: I don't know what could i do?! i used from this but it's not the answer .. $result->{@attributes}

Comment: If you can include the original XML, it would be easy enough to put an answer together.

Comment: i put the xml in my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [attributes](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) method of the [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php).

For example:

```
$source = <<<SOURCE
<BuyBoxEligibleOffers>
    <OfferCount condition="new" fulfillmentChannel="Amazon">1</OfferCount>
    <OfferCount condition="new" fulfillmentChannel="Merchant">10</OfferCount>
</BuyBoxEligibleOffers>
SOURCE;

$elements = simplexml_load_string($source);

foreach ($elements as $element) {
    echo "condition: " . $element->attributes()->condition . ", fulfillmentChannel: " . $element->attributes()->fulfillmentChannel . "<br>";
}
```

Will result in:

> condition: new, fulfillmentChannel: Amazon
>
> condition: new, fulfillmentChannel: Merchant